# Import KML file and update a table in a MySQL database using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, xml, laravel, kml

I have a KML file that looks like XML. I need to upload this file and update a MySQL database. The data is like this:

```
<Document>
    <name>GPSWaypoints-2020-10-16.kml</name>
    <Style id="inline">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="waypoint">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon61.png</href></Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>Waypoints</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>WPT 0011</name>
            <TimeStamp><when>2020-09-26T08:21:14Z</when></TimeStamp>
            <styleUrl>#waypoint</styleUrl>
            <Point><coordinates>-74.91270224,10.8081995</coordinates></Point>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name="accuracy">
                    <displayName>Accuracy</displayName>
                    <value>3.216</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name="provider">
                    <displayName>Provider</displayName>
                    <value>gps</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I have this method to import the KML file:

```
public function uploadKML(Request $request)
    {
       $file      = $request->file('kml');
       $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $filename  = time() . "." . $request->kml->extension();
       $file->move(public_path('kml'), $filename);
       $path = $request->image->store('public');
       return response()->json(["message" => "Upload Success"]);      
    }
```

Now with the file after uploading, I need to read the KML and update the coordinates with the same ID of a table.

The ID is in the name field of the KML. For example, in the field `<name> WPT 0011 </name>` The ID would be 0011, without the WPT.

The update method that I currently have is:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data= Data::findOrFail($id);
        return $data->update($request->all());
    }
```

And this is my Data Model:

```
<?php

class Data extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'coordinates' ....];
}
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the file, you might not want to save the actual content in the database, but rather a file location reference, like `file/location/file.kml`. As for reading it, there's likely libraries to handle KML, or you could use XML logic to load/parse. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: which libraries can i use? Any recomendation ?

Comment: I don't know of any off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: What have yout ried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have saved the KML file and it is saved in public with public_path, but I don't know how to open it and update the data in a table already created. I need a method to read the file and update that data, the coordinates more specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, give the file to an XML parser (like SimpleXML).

Then, parse out the information you want from the XML file into a variable (an array of XML elements).

Then, update the database using SQL with the array's elements' contents.

Something like this, for one id and several coordinates per KML file (untested, just typing this in to give you an idea):

```php
<?php

// Connect to database here

$KMLFile = "foo.kml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($KMLFile);
$id = $xml->Document->Folder->Placemark->Name->__toString();
$coordinates = $xml->Document->Folder->Placemark->Point->Coordinates;
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($coordinates); $i++) {
  $coordinate = $coordinates[$i]->__toString();

  // You should now have an ID and a coordinate as a string;
  // Do what you need to do with the coordinate string
  // and add the result to your database with SQL

}
?>
```

This will probably not work as written, but I hope it gives you enough information to build what you want.

You could also parse the coordinates or any other information you want from the KML file by using Regular Expressions or other means, but the "XML way" is the more obvious, elegant, and robust way of doing it. It does require that your KML is well-formed XML, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

1. You can save file at physical location and
   have reference in db
2. You can either use blob data type or text or long text based on size of your file

Answer (score 0):

**1. Save file on persistent storage.**

You can use [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function to save file in disk then save file name in database as string.

```php
$file = $_FILES["field_name"];
$uploads_dir = "/var/www/public_html/uploads";
$tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];

// basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
// further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
$name = basename($file["name"]);
$upload_name = "$uploads_dir/$name";

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_name);

// save file name ($upload_name) in database
```

**2. Use `TEXT` field type to store file contents inside database.**

I won't recommend this method if file size is bigger.

**3. Parse file then update structed data**

Parse xml data using [`SimpleXML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) or [`xml_parse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php) function then process parsed data.